# Problem reading data back from Bluetooth on Flutter flutter_blue_plus

Tags: flutter, bluetooth

I am trying to read data back from a custom-built bluetooth board that simply sends back a string of data like this:
printf("Read 0x%2.2X%2.2X%2.2X%2.2X\n\r", d1, d2, d3, d4);

And the value I expect to get back is "Read 0xF2000080\n\r"
But what I get in the following flutter code is "RöØd 0xF2000080"
and sometimes different characters are the wrong ones in that string...  the code that runs the printf sends back what is stored in memory for many different memory locations

```
uartTx.onValueChangedStream.listen((event1) {
  processIncomingData(event1);
  String stringVal = String.fromCharCodes(event1);
  LLog.lLog(_tag, "build: uartTx event 1: String value ${stringVal}");
  String stringVal2 = "";
  event1.forEach((element) {
    stringVal2 += element.toRadixString(16);
  });
  LLog.lLog(_tag, "build: uartTx event 1: String 2 value ${stringVal2}");

  String hexVal = hex.encode(event1);
  LLog.lLog(_tag, "build: uartTx event 1: Hex value ${hexVal}");
});
```

```
void processIncomingData(List<int> newBytes) {
  // convert the List<int> to a list of <byte> sized objects
  Uint8List convBytes = Uint8List.fromList(newBytes);

  // convert the List<int> into a string:
  String stringVal = String.fromCharCodes(newBytes);
  // which looks a lot like this:
  // [9X0CAF01460E4103][AP0200][BL0200][CL0210][DV0A312E302E30]
  //  [ and ] apparently are delimiters/terminations between commands

  LLog.lLog(_tag, 'processIncomingData: Uint8List of bytes received are = $convBytes and the string conversion of that is $stringVal');
```

I tried to listen for incoming data on a bluetooth connection:

```
uartTx.onValueChangedStream.listen((event1) {
  processIncomingData(event1);
```

I get bad characters in the List received:

```
  processIncomingData(event1);
```

```
void processIncomingData(List<int> newBytes) {
  // convert the List<int> to a list of <byte> sized objects
  Uint8List convBytes = Uint8List.fromList(newBytes);
```

which looks like this:
"RöØd 0xF2000080"

I expect just a regular set of ascii characters instead:

"Read 0xF2000080\n\r"